# jQuery Validation URL or File

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) and I need to make a form.

```
UPLOAD: <input type="file" name="image"  /><br>
URL: <input type="text" name="images">
```

How do I make it so that at least one of these fields must be filled (i.e. `class="required"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [dependency-expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) in jQuery Validate.  If your form looks like what you showed (i.e. 2 inputs, one named `image` the other named `images`) you can do this:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
       image: {
          required: 'input[name="images"]:blank'
       },
       images: {
          required: 'input[name="image"]:blank'
       }
    }
});
```

So what happens is that when it goes to validate each form field, it checks the given expression, and if it returns true, then the current form field is required.  If it's false, then it's not.

Answer (score 0):

this might work haven't tested it out just wrote it as quicky to help u down the road

```
$(function() {
    $("input").focusout(function (){
        $('input').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('required');
            if($(this).val()){
                $(this).removeClass('required');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/uFxEq/)

Answer (score 0):

I usually add custom methods for such stuff. Try something like this.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .error {color: red}
    </style>

    <form id="testForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input name="image" class="oneof" />
        <br /><input name="images" type="file" class="oneof" />
        <br /><input type="submit" />
    </form>


    <script>
        // using custom methods
        $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("oneofelementsrequired", function(value, element, param) {
                element = element || false; 
                var $frm=$(element).parents('form:first'),
                    any=false, 
                    $ctrls=$frm.find( param );

                $ctrls.each( function(){
                    any = any || this.value != ''
                });
              return any; 
            }, "Please fill one of this fields");

            jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
                oneof: {oneofelementsrequired: '.oneof'}
            });

            $('#testForm').validate({
                submitHandler: function(){
                    alert('From is Ok');
                    return false;
                }
            });


        });

    </script>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clownfish/3XfWS/)